# Toast is changing orientation of the portrait only app

Tags: android, android-orientation, android-toast

Here is the mainfest :

```
 <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Main2Activity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>
```

We have two activities, orientation of both is **restricted to Portrait** as specified in Manifest. `MainActivity` is launching `Main2Activity`, `onBackPressed()` of `Main2Activity` is overridden and showing a `Toast` code is below:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Toast.makeText(Main2Activity.this,"This is from Second",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    super.onBackPressed();

}
```

**Problem Statement:**
1. Keep the phone in Landscape
2. Launch the App
3. `MainActivity` gets created in Portrait (no issue till here)
4. Launch `Main2Activity` from `MainActivity`, There is a button that do that
5. `Main2Activity` open up in portrait (no issue till here)
6. Press hardware back button, `Main2Activity` gets dissappered
7. `MainActivity` **shows up in landscape**  with Toast then it automatically changes to Portrait.
8. Device was on landscape during all these steps
9. Tried changing context to Application context but no luck
10. Removed the Toast and everything works as expected

**Why this behaviour in Point 7?**

[image: mainActivity]

[image: Main2Activity]

[image: After pressing the back button on Main2Activity]

Comment: try adding the toast after super.onBackPressed();

Comment: I tried it after onBackPressed() and it works as expected. But can you explain the reason behind it?

Comment: I don't know for sure but I think it runs some functions which involve the configurations behind the scene and you show your toast meanwhile, so it cannot get the portrait configuration you've set. I add my answer please approve it so others can see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the toast after super.onBackPressed();

Answer (score 0):

Change Your onBackPressed() override form this

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Toast.makeText(Main2Activity.this,"This is from Second",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    super.onBackPressed();

}
```

To this

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
      super.onBackPressed();
      Toast.makeText(Main2Activity.this,"This is from Second",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Hope it will works!!